# Complex Number Problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I  do not know how to do this.

4)a Use de Moivre's to show $\cos 5\theta = \cos \theta ( 16\cos^4\theta -20\cos^2\theta + 5)$
EASY DONE

b) Solve $\cos5\theta = 0$ then deduce $cos^2(\dfrac{\pi}{10}) = \dfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}$

Can get solve for but can't deduce

c) Write down $cos^2(\dfrac{3\pi}{10})$ , $cos^2(\dfrac{7\pi}{10})$ and $cos^2(\dfrac{9\pi}{10})$

Can't really get this.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(4b): clearly, $\pi/10$ is one of the solutions to $\cos 5\theta=0$.
Armed with this knowledge, use (4a) to arrive at a quadratic equation $16z^2-20z+5=0$, where $z = \cos^2(\pi/10)$.

(4c): $3\pi/10$ is another solution to (4b), hence it will be the other root of the quadratic equation above. The rest of the values follow easily from $\cos(\pi-\theta)$.

Comment: When you solve b. you will have a plus or minus option. How do you know which one $\frac{\pi}{10}$ corresponds to and how do you show it? That's what I was trying to get at with "can get solve but not deduce"

Comment: Well, you deduced that there are only 2 non-trivial solutions to (4b): $\pi/10$ and $3\pi/10$. The first one must necessarily be greater than the second since $\cos^2x$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Great, I see now thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

For part $b$, let $x = \cos \theta$.

Since $\cos 5\theta = \cos \theta(16 \cos^4 \theta - 20\cos^2\theta + 5)$, then $\cos 5\theta = 0$ implies that
$$x(16x^4-20x^2+5) = 0.$$

An obvious solution is $x=0$, but there are four others. Let $y = x^2$, then $16y^2-20y+5=0$. Using the quadratic formula, $$y=\frac{20}{32}\pm \frac{\sqrt{400-4\cdot 16\cdot 5}}{32} = \frac{20 \pm \sqrt{80}}{32} = \frac{20 \pm 4\sqrt{5}}{32} = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{5}}{8}.$$

Now, noting that $\cos 5\theta = 0$ exactly when $5\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, we observe that if $\theta = \frac{\pi}{10}$ is a zero. So, since we defined $x$ as $\cos\theta$, and $y$ as $x^2$, then we have $y=x^2=\cos^2\theta \implies \cos^2 \frac{\pi}{10} = \frac{5\pm\sqrt{5}}{8}$.

Now, we need to determine whether we're taking the positive or negative operation.

Note that $\cos \frac{\pi}{10} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. You should know this, because you should know that $\cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. And further note that for any $x > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $x^2 > \frac12$. Therefore, $\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{10} > \frac12$. Since $\sqrt{5} > 2$, then $5-\sqrt{5} < 3$, so $\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8} < \frac12$. Thus, this cannot be the solution, meaning that $\cos^2\frac{\pi}{10} = \frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}$ must be the solution.